# Existence of an orthogonal transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification, orthogonality

> Let $x,y,z \in \Bbb R^n,\ n \geq 3.$ Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^3.$ Does there exist an orthogonal transformation $\varphi$ sending $\text {span}\ \{x,y,z \}$ into $\text {span}\ \{e_1,e_2,e_3 \}\ $ such that $\varphi (y) = e_1\ $?

What we should have is that $\varphi (x) \cdot \varphi (y) = x \cdot y, \varphi (y) \cdot \varphi (z) = y \cdot z$ and $\varphi (x) \cdot \varphi (z) = x \cdot z.$ Now let $\varphi (x) = (x_1',x_2',x_3')$ and $\varphi (z) = (z_1',z_2',z_3').$ Then since $\varphi (y) = e_1$ it follows that $x_1' = x \cdot y$ and $z_1' = y \cdot z$ and $x_1'z_1' + x_2'z_2' + x_3'z_3' = x \cdot z.$ These three equations yield $x_2'z_2' + x_3'z_3' = (x \cdot z) - (x \cdot y) (z \cdot y).$ So if we fix $x_2' = z_2' = 0$ and $x_3' = 1$ then we have $z_3' = (x \cdot z) - (x \cdot y) (y \cdot z).$ So in fact there are uncountably many choices for $\varphi.$ Am I right?

Please check it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: what you mean by an "orthogonal transformation"? Any orthogonal matrix is a square matrix, so it can only exists if $n=3$

Comment: @Masacroso by orthogonal transformations I mean inner product preserving transformations.

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was wrong. If $y\cdot y\neq 1$ then such map cannot exists because $e_1\cdot e_1=1$. However if $y\cdot y=1$ then you can find orthonormal vectors $v,w\in V:=\operatorname{span}(x,y,z)$ such that the list $y,v,w$ is orthonormal, and define a linear map by $\varphi (y)=e_1,\, \varphi (v)=e_2$ and $\varphi (w)=e_3$

Comment: @Masacroso it may so happen that among the three vectors $x,y,z,$ two of them can be written as a linear combination of the remaining one. In such case you won't be able to find orthonormal vectors $v,w$ in the span of $x,y,z,$ since orthogonality (and hence orthonormality) implies independence. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: right, I overlooked it, it may happen that $x,y,z$ would not be linearly independent, so such map cannot be possible either